# Elegant way to replace multiple if statemens to throw exceptions

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, reformat

my application has a service where 3 methods perform some validation and depending on the returned result a different exception is thrown.

```
  if (!check1stCondition() {
    throw new ValidationException(message1);
  }

  if (!check2ndCondition)
    throw new ValidationException(message2);

  if (!check3rdCondition)
    throw new ValidationException(message3);
}
```

How could I reformat this code in order to be maintaneable in the future? In the future new checks could be performed.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an interface `Checker` providing a method `check` raising the exception when it's the case. You code can change to something like

```
public interface Checker {
    void check() throws ValidationException;
}

public class YourClass {
   private List<Checker> checkers; // initialize through (dependency inhecjetd?) constructor parameter or by simply enumerating checker in the constructor; I personally prefer the first way

   public void yourMethod() {
     for(Checkech checker : checkers) {
        checker.check();
     }
   }
}
```

You can obviously add parameters to `check` method in order to provide data to be validated...

UPDATED

If you do dot have control over condition-checking implementation, you can switch to something like this (see @Alberto Venturini's comment):

```
public interface Checker {
    boolean check();

    String message();
}

public class YourClass {
   private List<Checker> checkers; // initialize through (dependency inhecjetd?) constructor parameter or by simply enumerating checker in the constructor; I personally prefer the first way

   public void yourMethod() {
     for(Checkech checker : checkers) {
        if(!checker.check()) {
            throw new ValidationException(checker.message());
        }        
     }
   }
}
```

You can implement a similar solution with the first `Checker` definition using a `Map<String, Checker>` variable which maintains associations between check conditions and corresponding error message, but I definitely prefer the polymorphical approach proposed by @Alberto Venturini.

I hope this approach can help you to move your code toward a more open-closed solution!

Comment: Thx for the advice. But my check methods do not throw any exception, they throw if the condition is not met (condition returns false) so I have 3 different check methods with 3 different error messages

Comment: @dataProcs Do you have control over the checker code - i.e., can you change the signature of your `check` methods so that they throw exceptions? If that's not possible, you could extend the definition of the `Checker` class with an error message; then, in your method, wrap the call to `checker.check()` with an `if` block, e.g.: `if (!checker.check()) { throw new ValidationException(checker.errorMsg); }`.

Comment: I like Alberto Venturini's advice very muck: I update my response in order to include it!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have 3 different conditions with 3 different messages.
It worth to use smth like [Guava preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) or write your own.

Your code will like

```
checkState(check1stCondition(), message1);
checkState(check2stCondition(), message2);
```

You won't reduce `if's` completely. But at least you increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use polymorphism  to reduce if statements and improve maintainability.

Just use an interface like this

```
public interface Example {

void check() throws ValidationException;
}
```

and implement different behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way close to OOP. Note: i do not insist on it, just showing an alternative.

Firstly you can create a new class for each condition. And assuming you perform checking on some data it will looks like:

```
interface Condition {
    CustomData checkedData();
}

public class Condition1 implements Condition {
    private CustomData data;

    public Condition1(CustomData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Condition1(Condition condition) {
        this.data = condition.checkedData();
    }

    public CustomData checkedData() {
        // do condition checking here and return CustomData if it's ok
        // throw exception otherwise
    }
}
```

Then you can wrap each `Condition` in another one:

```
CustomData data = new Condition1(
                      new Condition2(
                          new Condition3(YOUR_DATA))).checkedData();
```

You will be sure now that your data is checked and ready for further work.

I believe it is easy to maintain.. if you need a few new checks, just add a few small classes as above and wrap your data in another `Condition`. If you want to change some condition, you don't have to look for it in common code. You have separate class for it.